# Functions's [[Scope]] property

Tags: javascript, scope

I have created a very simple example that will serve as an explanation to my question.
The code is pseudo-code, here it is:

```
var scopePosition = "global";

function outer() {
    var scopePosition = "outer";
}

// debugger; We reached this line to inspect Execution Contexts and Function Objects
outer();

// Execution Contexts
var GlobalExecutionContext = {
    variableObject: {
        scopePosition: "global",
        outer: "pointer to function object called `outer`"
    },
    scopeChain: [GlobalExecutionContext.variableObject],
    this: {}
};

//Function Objects
var outerFunctionObject = {
    [[Scope]]: "pointer to GlobalExecutionContext or GlobalExecutionContext.variableObject or 
    GlobalExecutionContext.scopeChain ???"
};
```

The question itself is when the function gets created where does its [[Scope]] property points to exactly? Is it the Execution Context it was created or Execution Context Variable Object or Executions Context Scope Chain?

My best guess would be GlobalExecutionContext.scopeChain, cause that way scope links won't be lost if we had a more nested function inside outer and the process is repeated.

Comment: Yes, it refers to the scope chain, although in the ES spec the scope chain is a linked list not an array.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I couldnt find information about this anywhere but its kinda logical and it makes sense how Closures, for example, are implemented inside JS. There is nothing different between closures and regular variable lookups except that Variable Objects can not be garbage collected if there is a pointer to them. At least that what I think.

Comment: Where did you look and found about [[Scope]] internal properties and execution contexts?

Comment: Most information I found here http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures. But what happens with function object and the [[Scope]] property once the function declaration is reached, that information I couldnt find anywhere.

Comment: Oh my, thanks for the link. That article seems to be a rip-off from the original http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#scope-chain, which explains the same thing much better. Also, notice that it discusses ES3, which is ancient. Maybe have a look at [the second edition](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/#execution-context).